# Android java zipping files and send with intent

Tags: java, android, zip

I have this method that zips files from a List and another method that uses this for send it with mail through intent.

My problem is that when I send it two or three times the app crashes and shows me this.

```
E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                 java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:89)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
at com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaDatai.zip(VisaDatai.java:1172)
at com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaDatai.sendZippedMail(VisaDatai.java:207)
at com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaDatai.getFiles(VisaDatai.java:298)
at com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaDatai$7$1.run(VisaDatai.java:1823)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

The main problem (I think) is in this message

```
at com.waffles.vatsandbats.VisaDatai.zip(VisaDatai.java:1172)
```

That refers to this

```
in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i)
                .getCanonicalFile());
```

Here's the method that creates the zip and that has the error code

```
public static File zip(List<File> files, String filename) {
    File zipfile = new File(filename);
    // Create a buffer for reading the files
    FileInputStream in=null;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        // create the ZIP file
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                zipfile));
        // compress the files
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
             in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i)
                    .getCanonicalFile());
            // add ZIP entry to output stream
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files.get(i).getName()));
            // transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
        // complete the ZIP file
        out.close();
        return zipfile;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The list of files that I zip is several PrintedPdfDocuments with images and texts (this class has it owns disadvantages but Im lazy changing that right now)

I just can't find the problem. Maybe I need to change the method that zips. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is kind of odd as it looks like the `FileOutputStream` isn't being closed properly although `out.close()` should close it. Are any other exceptions occurring? Typically you will close your streams in a `finally` block so they are properly cleaned up if an exception occurs. If one occurs in your case the stream might never be closed.

Comment: I've changed all my methods to close in the final block but seemed to forget that in this one. I don't think it's going to work better but it is better anyway. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The problem seems to be in this file 
in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i).getCanonicalFile());

Comment: Why aren't you just passing the file itself into the FileInputStream constructor? getCanonicalFile says it returns a new File

Comment: What do you mean it takes all the files you have? Don't you want to put all the files in the `files` list into a single zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I closed the FileInputStream inside the for loop. So every time it looped and opened the stream I also closed it.

I added a own try catch for the close block at finally just for being sure but when I took away the close section in the for loop it crashed.

Here's the working code

```
public  File zip(List<File> files, String filename) {
    File zipfile = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream in=null;
    ZipOutputStream out=null;
    // Create a buffer for reading the files
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        // create the ZIP file
        out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                zipfile));
        // compress the files
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {

            in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));

            // add ZIP entry to output stream
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files.get(i).getName()));
            // transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

        try {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            out.closeEntry();

            out.close();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return zipfile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close your streams in a finally block to make sure they are closed properly even when an exception occurs.

Also using `getCanonicalFile()` creates a new file when you are creating your `FileInputStream`. You probably want:

```
in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));
```

Comment: I closed my streams in a finally block. It works better but it still crashes and points at the same line of code....in = new FileInputStream(files.get(i));